# Replace column value based other column values pyspark data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have the following spark data frame.

```
Date_1         Value     Date_2 
20-10-2021       1        Date 
20-10-2021       2        Date 
21-10-2021       3        Date 
23-10-2021       4        Date
```

I would like to fill `Date_2` values by adding `Date_1 + (Value-1)`.

The output that I would like to see is the following.

```
Date_1         Value     Date_2 
20-10-2021       1        20-10-2021
20-10-2021       2        21-10-2021 
21-10-2021       3        23-10-2021
23-10-2021       4        26-10-2021
```

I have tried this using pyspark.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('Date_2', F.date_add(df['Date_1'], (df['Value'] -1)).show()
```

But I am getting `TypeError: Column is not iterable`.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to parse SQL function DATE_ADD like this:

```
(
    df
    .withColumn("Value", F.col("Value").cast("int"))
    .withColumn("Date_2", 
                F.expr('DATE_ADD(Date_1, Value - 1)')
               )
)
```

DATE_ADD(Date_1, Value - 1) will add to each row in *Date_1* column value from column *Value* -1 (counting in days).

Additionally (if you don't have it done yet) Value columns should be INT. If you would have there for example DOUBLE type, *AnalysisException* occur.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks.

Comment: when I take this solution to real one I am getting a strange error. Says ```AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'col' ``` do you have any idea about this ```col```?

Comment: Do you use F.col("Value") where `F is from pyspark.sql import functions as F`?
I see similar error only if I replaced "F.col()" into "df.col()":
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'`

Comment: Don't you accidentally use `f.col()` instead `F.col()` where f in your case is something like this `f = open(file_with_data)`?

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the function [date_add](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_add) is *(col, int)*. Therefore, you cannot use directly `df['Value']`.

try this :

```py
df = df.withColumn('Date_2', F.expr("date_add(Date_1, Value -1)")).show()
```

Comment: Can you make it a bit clear where the quotation which starts on ```date_add``` ends?  AND Can it iterate on ```Value-1``` as well?